# PHPMyAdmin Update Trigger Error

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I was attempting to add a trigger to a table in my database via the PHPMyAdmin trigger add trigger tool.

I have two tables in the same database: table_A and table_B.
I am checking to see if the updated value that is returned from the trigger is equal to 1. If so, I would like to update a value in table_B. Here is my code:

```
SELECT var_a FROM INSERTED
IF var_a = 1 THEN 
    UPDATE table_B
    SET table_B.someVal = table_B.someVal + 1;
END IF;
```

The error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL      server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF var_a = 1 THEN 
    UPDATE table_B
    SET table_B.someVal = table_B.someVal + 1;
E' at line 2

Help is appreciated. Is this a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a syntax error. Note that MySQL does not use the special `INSERTED` table (that's special to SQL Server.)

Even if you had a table named `INSERTED`, that's still not valid MySQL syntax for a trigger; at a minimum you'd need to end the SELECT statement with a semicolon. But a trigger is not allowed to return a resulset, you'd need to do a SELECT ... INTO, or use a cursor.

Use the "NEW" and "OLD" keywords to qualify references to columns in the row being updated.

To check the value assigned to the `var_a` column, reference `NEW.var_a`

For example:

```
  IF NEW.var_a = 1 THEN
    UPDATE table_B
       SET table_B.someCol = tableB.someCol + 1;
  END IF;
```

Comment: Ah silly me. Thanks for the words of advice, that did the trick!